# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException log4net

Tags: c#, log4net

I am randomly getting this exception. From the below stack trace i can understand that it is originating from the log4net functionality.

```
LogExceptionValue  - 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: capacity was less than the current size.
Parameter name: value
at System.Collections.ArrayList.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
at System.Collections.ArrayList.Add(Object value)
at log4net.Util.LogReceivedEventHandler.Invoke(Object source, LogReceivedEventArgs e)
at log4net.Util.LogLog.OnLogReceived(Type source, String prefix, String   message, Exception exception)
at log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.InternalConfigure(ILoggerRepository  repository)
at log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(ILoggerRepository repository)
at log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()
at Loggers.LoggerBase.LogMessage(LogInformation logInformation)
at LookupByReasonCode(String reasonCode)
```

Code for Log4Net

```
 /// <summary>
    ///  Logs message based on logger.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logInformation">Log Information </param>
    protected void LogMessage(LogInformation logInformation)
    {
        this.log = LogManager.GetLogger(logInformation.Logger);
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logInformation.Request))
        {
            ThreadContext.Properties["request"] = logInformation.Request;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logInformation.Response))
        {
            ThreadContext.Properties["response"] = logInformation.Response;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logInformation.ResponseCode))
        {
            ThreadContext.Properties["responsecode"] = logInformation.ResponseCode;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logInformation.Keys))
        {
            ThreadContext.Properties["keys"] = logInformation.Keys;
        }

        //// Logs exception
        this.Log(logInformation.Message, logInformation.LogLevel, logInformation.Exception);
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide the code that is causing the exception. Right now, there's nothing we can do to help.

Comment: As  `XmlConfigurator.Configure` is mentioned in the stack trace please also show your config

Comment: I have edited my question with the Log4net Code. Please let me know if you need further information

Comment: You have an XML file to configure log4net, correct?  It looks like you have an invalid value in one of the configuration elements, but we can't say for sure unless you show the configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting this *intermittently* it's most likely because you are **loading the log4net configuration on every single logging call** and two threads are trying and load it at the same time.

Move `XmlConfigurator.Configure();` to your startup program and only call it once.

Comment: yeah. This could be the one of the reason i thought,  let me try and give you update